# Question mark when using multiple citations in one `\cite{}` block

Tags: citing

In my document, when I use `\cite{paper1, proceedings1, paper2}`, it appears as `[1, ?, ?]` but when I write them separately like `\cite{paper1}, \cite{proceedings1}, \cite{paper2}`, the text is `[1], [5], [4]`.

What would cause this?

Comment: Have you tried removing the space after each comma?

Comment: @sudosensei Yeah, that worked.

Comment: @sudosensei, why don't you write an answer?

Comment: Happy to hear that, cagirici. @MarioS.E. Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use multiple keys in a `\cite` command, you should use a comma delimiter and not a comma+space. `\cite{paper1,proceedings1,paper2}` resolves all three citations correctly.

From [here](http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Multiple_citations):

> ## Multiple citations
>
> When a sequence of multiple citations are needed, you should use a single `\cite{}` command. The citations are then separated by commas. Note that you must not use spaces between the citations. Here's an example:
>
> `\cite{citation01,citation02,citation03}`
>
> The result will then be shown as citations inside the same brackets.